# The name 'DAL' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a multi layer project that has a DAL layer and a BLL layer
Iget the error below when I try calling the DAL layer from the BLL layer
The name 'DAL' does not exist in the current context
DAL layer's reference to BLL layer is also done

BLL Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
namespace BLL
{
    public class Panel
    {
        public static SqlDataReader GetInformationPanel(string PanelId)
        {
            SqlDataReader RetVal = DAL.Panel.GetInformationPanel(PanelId);
            return RetVal;
        }
    }
}
```

DAL Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace DAL
{
    public class Panel
    {

        public static SqlDataReader GetInformationPanel(string PanelId)
        {
            SqlDataReader Val = DALBase.EReader("select * from TBLPanel where PanelId = " + PanelId + "", System.Data.CommandType.Text, new SqlParameter[] { });
            return Val;
        }
    }
}
```

I also get the error below when I add Using DAL;

> The type or namespace name 'DAL' could not be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference

Screen capture of my solution:

[image]

Source Project:
http://s3.picofile.com/d/8e066a6b-c555-4dd3-a18e-b8bf3047ed5f/Viber.rar

Comment: Well?  Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: can you pls add a printescreen or your solution explorer, you forget add using DAL, something like DAL = MyprojectName.DAL.

Comment: @Juan Ruiz de Castilla
http://uupload.ir/files/n7s1_untitled.png

Comment: It is what @JuanRuizdeCastilla said, there is no using DAL; in your BLL code that you provided.  If you can't add the using it is because you haven't referenced the DAL project in your BLL project.  Based on your screenshot, DAL is referenced, you need to add the using statement.

Comment: @JasonWilczak How do i add the using statement ?
I get this error when I try to reference the BLL to DAL

***A reference to 'BLL' could not be added.Adding this project as a reference would cause a circular dependency ***

Comment: You need to add the reference BLL to DAL not vice versa, if you already add, just need to add "using statement". provide a printescreen to help you better. using DAL; could be work.

Comment: @mohammadtajari You can't do that since you are already referencing DAL in your BLL project, based on your screenshot.  You need to add the using statement in your BLL code Panel class.  See my answer.

Comment: I would remove the reference to DAL in your BLL references and then re-add it.  I created a small sample app and I am able to access the DAL class with just adding a reference and no using statement.

Comment: Remove the DAL reference and add it again as a Project reference (Add Reference > Solution > Projects). Then rebuild the solution.

Comment: Also, check that the build order is DAL then BLL.

Comment: @Jasen   I did it , didn't work

Comment: No idea, maybe you can share your app lol, to try to help you better.

Comment: @Juan Ruiz de Castilla
http://s3.picofile.com/d/8e066a6b-c555-4dd3-a18e-b8bf3047ed5f/Viber.rar

Comment: the solution is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in Your BLL

```
using DAL;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you have forgot to add reference to your DAL project in the BLL project. You can do so by right click on the BAL project name -> Add -> Reference and select DAL project from Projects in the Solution section (from the left side panel)

Comment: Based on their screenshot there is a reference to DAL

Comment: @CharithS uupload.ir/files/n7s1_untitled.png